# Ember - ember.debug.js:19746 Error: Failed to create an instance of 'adapter:application'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data, ember-rails

I am building an ember app and am attempting to connect to a rails API, to read in data from a questions end point.

These are two separate applications.

My Code is as follows:

adapters/application.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import ActiveModelAdapter from 'active-model-adapter';

export default DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v2'
});
```

models/questions.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  text:  DS.attr('string'),
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  debateTopicId:  DS.attr('string'),
  releaseAt: DS.attr('date'),
  expiresAt:  DS.attr('date')
});
```

routes/questions.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.findAll('question');
  }
});
```

templates/questions.hbs

```
<h2>This is the Questions Feed</h2>

{{#each model as |question|}}
  <h3>{{question.id}} - {{question.text}}</h3>
{{/each}}
```

The end point I am attempting to call to is:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v2/questions
```

I get the error:

```
ember.debug.js:19746 Error: Failed to create an instance of 'adapter:application'. Most likely an improperly defined class or an invalid module export.
    at instantiate (ember.debug.js:1477)
    at lookup (ember.debug.js:1336)
    at Object.lookup (ember.debug.js:1255)
    at Class.lookup (ember.debug.js:34526)
    at ContainerInstanceCache.instanceFor (container-instance-cache.js:62)
    at ContainerInstanceCache._findInstance (container-instance-cache.js:51)
    at ContainerInstanceCache.get (container-instance-cache.js:39)
    at Class.retrieveManagedInstance (store.js:2105)
    at Class.lookupAdapter (store.js:2111)
    at Class.adapterFor (store.js:2051)
```

Any ideas what the issue is?

Comment: Are you properly installing and importing the [active model adapter](https://github.com/ember-data/active-model-adapter)?

Comment: I installed the active model adapter and added it too the adapters/application.js file ( edits made to code above ).  Im still getting the same error, and other ideas?

Comment: You need to remove the DS from DS.ActiveModelAdapter

Comment: That worked I am now hitting the server, however I am now getting a new error, ember.debug.js:19746 Error: Ember Data Request GET http://localhost:3000/api/v2/questions returned a 0
Payload (Empty Content-Type)... Any ideas?

Comment: You were trying to import a module that does not exist, the active model adapter was extracted out of ember data a long time ago, when you installed the addon you imported the correct module but you were still looking for it on the `DS` module.